# Nutch 2.2.1 setup with HBase on hadoop cluster

Tags: apache, hadoop, web-crawler, hbase, nutch

I have referred this tutorial (http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial) to setup Nutch 2.2.1.with Hbase. I have completed the setup as given in the tutorial, but how to Crawl and store the data into Hbase tables is not mentioned clearly.

Can you please refer me to some relevant links/books for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Most helpful for me was this:

http://sujitpal.blogspot.cz/2011/01/exploring-nutch-20-hbase-storage.html

Mapping to hbase is defined here **NUTCH_HOME/conf/gora-hbase-mapping.xml**.
So if everything is configured correctly, the crawl script should store it for you.

I have the same configuration and had many many problems to get it work, here are some tips:

Tip 1: be careful about table name

I configure also these properties:

```
<property>
  <name>storage.schema.webpage</name>
  <value>webpage</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>storage.crawl.id</name>
  <value>babu</value>
</property>
```

This configuration will crawl data into babu_webpage table in hbase when you give argument -crawlId in script write simple 'babu' -> $CRAWL_ID.

```
$bin/nutch fetch $commonOptions -D fetcher.timelimit.mins=$timeLimitFetch $batchId -crawlId $CRAWL_ID -threads 50
```

Tip 2: if you have bad table name Nutch still write on console success.

Tip 3: how to simple see if there is crawled something in hbase:

go to  ./bin/hbase shell

```
list
scan 'babu_webpage'
```

Comment: Hi, I have set-up Hadoop 0.20.204 and hbase 92.x and nutch-2.2.1, I have seen that hadoop and hbase are properly working as I have successfully created a table in hbase shell and inserted values in it.

Comment: But the problem I am facing is that while setting Nutch-2.2.1 I am getting ClassNotFoundException: GoraOutputFormat. But in $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/lib I can see gora-core*.jar which contains this class GoraOutputFormat.class. Please help regarding this. I searched over net but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Yes I know that hell with jar...after few experiments we setup it with these versions hadoop-core-1.2.0.jar, hbase-0.90.6-cdh3u5.jar, gora-core-0.3.jar , gora-hbase-0.3.jar in NUTCH_HOME/lib and dont forget have the same version in HBASE_HOME/ hbase-0.90.6-cdh3u5.jar ...this is the only version we manage to work together...

Comment: So, do I even have to setup hadoop-1.2 version and hbase 0.90.6 version or only copy these jars ?

Comment: Can you give your contact, I would like to contact you in future if I face some issues with Nutch?

Answer (score 1):

I followed this [tutorial](http://saskia-vola.com/nutch-2-2-elasticsearch-1-x-hbase/) and I ran Nutch with indexing to Elasticsearch with no problem. The relevant infomation for you are six commands on the end of the article.

```
bin/nutch inject <seed-url-dir>
bin/nutch generate -topN <n>
bin/nutch fetch -all
bin/nutch parse -all
bin/nutch updatedb
bin/nutch elasticindex <clustername> -all
```

I created urls directory in NUTCH_HOME, where I placed file seed.txt. In this file are url adresses to crawl. Next five commands I put to the script file and ran it int infinitive loop. If you will follow only your tutorial, you won't have to use last command bin/nutch elasticindex, of course. The topN number I sat up to 50, because with higher number it sometimes got stuck. But it can be only in my case.